# How to update a image using AJAX in corephp and mysql

Tags: php

I have a admin panel from which my website's front-end is running. I have written a update function, which is not working.

I have tried many different codes, but still not able to make it. I have all the necessary files ready but still update function is not working.

```
$result= $this->CommonClass1->NormalQuery(
                "UPDATE `sliders` 
                SET ".$image." 
                WHERE id=".$data['hiddenval']." "); //this is the code, which is not working.

$result= $this->CommonClass1->NormalQuery(
                "UPDATE `testimonial` 
                    SET `name`='".$data['name']."', 
                        `message`='".$data['message']."',
                        `designation`='".$data['designation']."' ".$image." 
                WHERE id=".$data['hiddenval']." "); //this the similar code, which is running smoothly.
```

I expect the actual results would to be the proper functioning of the update function, but the submit button shows the processing comment..

Comment: echo your query with your update value and direct run on `phpmyadmin` so you will get a better idea

Comment: How can I do so?

Comment: Please do an `echo $image` and show us what is in that variable

Comment: Can you tell me where should I write the echo $image;?

Comment: Just before the first line of code you show us

Comment: Nothing worked. It is not showing anything.

I have tried this code :

$image=!empty($data['image'])?",slider_image='".$data['image']."'":'';
echo $image;

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work assuming your variable $image is a url of the actual image or maybe some base64 image data and photo is the column to update.

```php
// $image = 'https://linktoimage.jpg';
// $image = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0i1MTJweCI+PHBhdGg=';

$result = $this->CommonClass1->NormalQuery("UPDATE `sliders` SET `photo` = '$image' WHERE id = " . $data['hiddenval'] . " " );
```